# .htaccess rewrite: how to remove all directories but the first and second?

Tags: .htaccess, regex

I'm trying to get a specific .htaccess rewrite done, but my regex skills are limiting me to do so;

example 1: www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.txt should become www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/file.txt

example 2: www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.txt should also become www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/file.txt

example 3: www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4%2Ffile.txt should also become www.domain.com/dir1/dir2/file.txt

And so on. As I do not know on forehand what dir2, dir3, dir4, and so on will be, regex probably should be used. Also, I do not know on forehand how deep the directories will go (if there will be a dir3, dir4 or even dir5 at all). Urlencoded slashes also should be recognized. Using php to handle this is not an option.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: But you know `dir1`?

Comment: Yes, dir1 is known

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To strip the third and subsequent directories:

```
RewriteRule ^/(dir1)/([^/]+)/(.+)/([^/]+)$ $1/$2/$4 [L]
```

Comment: Not just the last directory, as I do not know how many dirs there will be passed. So I want to strip all directories but the first 2 and the filename. So in my examples only the dir3/ (example 1) and dir3/dir4/ (example 2) parts should be stripped. Hopefully you can help me further

Comment: @Tijmen See my edit.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I'm almost there now. Your solution works, however because it needs the 3rd dir (and this is optional), I've added a 2nd rewriterule now to catch the urls without a 3rd dir. What still is a problem that the third and subsequent dirs might be separated by an urlencoded slash (%2F) instead of /. I'm still figuring out a solution for that.

Comment: @Tijmen Please add an example of this to your question.

Comment: Example 3 added.

Comment: @Tijmen Apache is supposed to [decode any escaped characters](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), so this should just work.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, problem solved. Apparently, apache only decodes these characters if the directive "AllowEncodedSlashes On" is set for the appropriate vhost (in httpd.conf doesnt work).